# Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined. I am making a video chat app

Tags: javascript, socket.io, io

```
<head>
    <title>Whiplash Chat</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel = "icon" href = 
"../MicrosoftTeams-image (3).png" 
        type = "image/x-icon">
</head>

<body style="text-align: center; background-color:blue">
    <div id="startPage">
        <img src="../MicrosoftTeams-image (3).png">
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Name">
        <br>
        <br>
        <button onclick="joinCall()" class="joinButton">Join Call</button>
    </div>
<div id="inCall">
        <video id="video"muted></video>
</div>
        <script src="main.js"></script>
        <script src="../node_modules/requirejs/require.js"></script>
        <!-- <script type="module" src="../node_modules/simple-peer/simplepeer.min.js"></script> -->
        
</body>
```

This is my HTML code

And this is my JS Code :

```
  function joinCall(){
      document.getElementById("startPage").style.display = "none";
  var SimplePeer = new RTCPeerConnection();
    let socket = io();
    const video = document.getElementById("video");
    let client = {};
    let currentFilter;

    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true }).then(function(stream) {
        //video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
        video.srcObject = stream;
        video.play();

    
  })
}
```

I am getting the error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined

I am making a video chat app with Peer Connection

Comment: Perhaps `let socket = io();` should be` `let socket = new io();`?

Comment: It still tells me the same error

Comment: Have you added this tag `<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>` ?

Comment: ```GET http://127.0.0.1:5500/socket.io/socket.io.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)``` this is what it tells

Comment: Please help. Its

Comment: PLEASE HELP GUYS

Comment: Instead of leaving comments with clarifications, you should edit the question to include that information. That's what the quality filter is there for, to make you add details to the question. Bypassing that with filler text defeats the purpose.

Comment: It's telling you that `io` isn't defined. What is `io`? Is that from a third party library or something you wrote?

Comment: Third Party library using npm js